# The company recruiter taking long to contact me

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, recruitment, follow-up

I received a call from a recruiter, from a bank that I applied almost a month before. The recruiter called and left me a message (on Wednesday 2-24), I called back, but got her voice mail. I left a message and then called a 2nd time a few hours later with the same result but I did get a text reply saying that she was in a meeting and that she would call me back.

I waited until next day in the afternoon and call again. She replied that she was off, and that she would call me.

Again I waited and received no response.  Finally I sent her a text on Friday saying that I understood of her busy schedule, that I was very interested in the position. She replied "in a meeting", but never contacted me.

Should I text back? (I don't have any other way of contacting her.) if I do, what should I write? I am still looking at other jobs and have an interview this week, but this is the job that I really want.

Comment: From your description you have sent enough messages for now (one message Wed, Thu and Fri). Wait at least a week before calling again. The next move is hers.

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is whether this person, who can't do you the courtesy of a timely reply, is someone with whom you want to do business.

Comment: Banks, unless they are small community based ones, are very impersonal entities. I am sure that recruiter has many more positions to fill other than what you have applied to. Don't get this the wrong way but, you are just a drop of water in the ocean for her. When and if she will have time in her schedule she will contact you. Provided that position has not been filled by the time this happens. Unless your qualifications are somewhat hard to find, I wouldn't waste any time waiting for her to call back.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I live in a small town in Florida. I found out that the recruiter is in Pennsylvania. I checked the employers website to see the status of my application. It says under review.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience a recruiter will be desperate to make contact with you if they think you are a good match for a position and the opportunity is still open. I would suggest this opportunity is gone now so it's not worth following up again. The only thing you might want to do in a few days is send a message to say something along the lines of 'I guess this position is no longer available, thanks for making initial contact with me and please do keep me in mind for any similar opportunities in the future'. This might keep you at the front of their mind.

It's possible that when the recruiter called you they thought you were a good candidate and the job was still open. Perhaps shortly after that the job was filled. From my experience that's when a recruiter will stop taking your calls, unless they have other posts you are suited to. You might ask how the job could be filled so quickly if they were trying to contact you? Even if a recruiter has 3 candidates being interviewed for a post it makes sense to keep advertising a position. If those 3 don't work out, you need to have a few more people in the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you.That's what I had in mind. I do have an interview Thursday with BOFA. Thanks again